# Gmail API for monitoring login activity

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

Hey guys I am looking for an Google or Gmail API which will monitor the user login activity of his/her gmail account.  I got a app which does the same

Here is a link.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.logdog.websecurity&hl=en

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To monitor the login activities of all of your account's users, you may want to use the [Reports API: Login Activity Report](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-login). Each report uses the basic report endpoint request with report-specific parameters such as a user's email. The maximum time period for each report is the last 180 days.

> Note: The login activity report only audits explicit password and SAML-based single sign-on (SSO) logins.

To retrieve all logins for all of your domain's services, use the following GET HTTP request and include the authorization token described in the [authorization documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/authorizing.html).

Comment: Hi Abielita, thanks for the answer.  I just want to know is it only for Gsuite domain users which are registered on my domain?
Or can I view the login activity of the gmail user ending their email with @gmail.com

Basically I want to track (at)gmail.com domain for login activity